# Removing DRM from android using root

Tags: root-access, security, drm

I would like to know what would one have to do to remove DRM (Digital Restrictions/"Rights" Management) completely from an Android phone one has root access to.

So far I have thought about removing /etc/drm, /etc/dcmrcm and /system/bin/drmserver

Thanks in advance!